# Put line object on top in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, line, contour

I have a colored contour plot which is interpolated from a set of data locations.  I would like to show the data locations on top of the contour plot.  For some reason, the colored contour plot always covers up the data locations when I plot them together.  It does not matter which one I plot first.

Why is this?  And how can I force the data points to be plotted on top?

**EDIT:** Here's a picture (There are also more points in the middle of the triangle):

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the order of lines in a Matlab figure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674700/how-to-change-the-order-of-lines-in-a-matlab-figure)

Comment: @Jonas, I tried using `uistack(h,'top')` where `h` is the handle for the data points, but the color plot still comes on top.

Comment: Can you post an example, please?

Comment: @Jonas, the script is large and in several files, so it is not convenient to post.  I will try to come up with something simple, yet similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things to check in this situation.  Sorry for repeating anything that you've already tried.

1. Make sure that `hold on` has been set, so that you are actually plotting both datasets.
2. Try the different renderers available.  That is, try the following, one at a time.

   set(gcf,'renderer','opengl')
   set(gcf,'renderer','painters')
   set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer')

   Note that there are other trades between these rendering options.  For example, I suspect   that 'painters' may provide the best render, but it will be very slow to update, and nearly impossible to (for example) rotate.
3. This is kind of a long shot, but try simply making your markers bigger.  That is, replace

   `plot3(xdata, ydata, xdata, '.')`

   with

   `plot3(xdata, ydata, zdata, '.', 'markersize', 50)`
4. If this is a 2D plot (I see from your edit that it is), then you can use the third dimension to force the correct order.  All 2D items are actually plotted in 3D, with Z=0.  Therefore if you want your markers to plot above the surface, you can replace:

   `plot(xdata, ydata, 'o')`

   with

   `plot3(xdata, ydata, 0.1, 'o')`

   Surfaces and lines are considered very different items b Matlab and the interlying graphics system.  Ordering these different sorts of items sometimes requires a bit of help.

Comment: @astay13: `hold on` is indeed the first thing you should check. +1

Comment: @Pursuit, thanks for the suggestions.  I did try `hold on` and making the markers bigger, neither fixes the main problem, which is that the colormap covers everything else.  (See my edit above for an example)  Also, I don't know if its just my old version of MATLAB (R2007b), but it doesn't seem to know what to do with the 'renderer' property.

Comment: @astay13  Thanks for the figure update in the question.  See (4), just added.