# Marker transparency in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, transparency, line, marker

I would like to know if there is possible to set the transparency of a line marker to opaque in order to improve my animation ([satellite movement around the Earth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620646/invalid-object-handle-error-in-matlab)).

Comment: See if any of these ideas work for your current problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8163002/931379

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I had already tried those ideas and the number 2 is the unique that works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  just set the plot properties of **MarkerFaceColor** and **MarkerEdgeColor** to the same one.

```
x = 1:10; y = log2(x);
plot(x,y,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 1 0],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 1 0],'MarkerSize',30,'Marker','v')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, your solution does not work for my 3D animation.

Comment: @jfpeji, can you give an example of your code, I will be able to help.

Comment: You can access my animation code clicking on the highlighted words (satellite movement around the Earth) of the question.