# Choose which line most forward in plot

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I am trying to plot some results from experiment.
I have around 50 lines and I had like one of them to be wider and show it on top.

The code is as following:

```
figure(1)
hold on
plot(Time,Delta(:,2),'red','linewidth',2)
for k = 1:i-1
    if k == Index    
        plot(Time,Delta_PWM{1,k},'color','black','linewidth',2)
    else
        plot(Time,Delta_PWM{1,k},'color',[160 160 160]/255)
    end
end
```

I had like the plot at `k == Index` not only to be wider but also to show above other lines because so far im getting the following:

[image]

What im trying to get is the black line to be above all the grey lines.

I managed to solve it by doing:

```
figure(1)
hold on
plot(Time,Delta(:,2),'red','linewidth',2)
for k = 1:i-1
    if k ~= Index    
        plot(Time,Delta_PWM{1,k},'color',[160 160 160]/255)
    end
end
plot(Time,Delta_PWM{1,Index},'color','k','linewidth',2)
```

However im trying to understand if there is some more intelligent way.

Thank you

Comment: This question is related. It answers the question in the title, but not the more general question "how can I do this in a more intelligent way". [How to change the order of lines in a Matlab figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674700/how-to-change-the-order-of-lines-in-a-matlab-figure)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7675219/7328782), you can move a line to the front using the function `uistack`. But you can also remove the `if` and duplicated code from your program by storing the line handles in an array and modifying the appropriate one:

```matlab
figure
hold on
N = size(Delta_PWM,2);
h = gobjects(1,N);      % Pre-allocate an array of handles
for k = 1:N
    h(k) = plot(Time,Delta_PWM{1,k},'color',[160 160 160]/255)
end
uistack(h(Index),'top');                       % Move line to the front
set(h(Index),'Color','Black','LineWidth',2);   % Change its properties
```