# Changing the plotting order with 2nd yaxis

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an issue with changing the plotting order when I am plotting on two different y-axes. I want the plot on the left axis to be infront of the plot on the right yaxis. I already treid to change the order of calling the plotting functions, as you can see below. Further, I looked into this post:

[Similar StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674700/how-to-change-the-order-of-lines-in-a-matlab-figure)

But the accepted answer did not help me. I guess the issue is that I only change the order on one axis.. Also the command uistack only results in an error for I guess the same reason. Any help is highly appreciated.

My code:

```matlab
V = horzcat((-2:0.1:2), (2:-0.1:-2));
t = (0:0.01234568:1.01);
T = (0:25:2025);

figure(30);   
yyaxis right
plot(t ,V, 'Linewidth',3); hold all;
xlabel('Time / s');ylabel('Voltage / V');
set(gca,'FontSize',fontsize, 'LineWidth',2,'TickLength',[0.025 0.025])
xticks([0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]);
ylim([-2, 2]),
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.MinorTick = 'on';
ax.XAxis.MinorTickValues = (0:0.05:1);
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTick', 'on')
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTickValues', (-2:0.25:2))
    
yyaxis left
top = plot(t ,T, 'Linewidth',3); hold all;
xlabel('Time / s');ylabel('Temperature / K');
ax = gca;
%ax.YAxis.MinorTick = 'on';
%ax.YAxis.MinorTickValues = (250:50:650);
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTick', 'on')
set(ax.YAxis, 'MinorTickValues', (250:50:650))
chH = get(gca,'Children');
set(gca,'Children',[chH(end);chH(1:end-1)]);
uistack(top, 'top');
```

What it looks like now:

[image]

As you can see the orange line is in front of the blue one, however I would like to have it the other way around.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would ask the "second issue" as another question - it is a second issue and apparently unrelated!

Comment: Okay, I changed it :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `get(gca,'Children')` returns only one line object! And it is the blue one. So this code actually does nothing.
But I believe the problem comes from the `yyaxis` method. According to MATLAB [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html):

> **Tips**
> ...
>
> - The Children property of the Axes object only contains the children for the active side. To access all the children for both sides, use the `allchild` function.

> **Axes Properties**
> Axes properties related to the y-axis have two values. However, MATLAB® gives access only the value for the active side. For example, if the left side is active, then the YLim property of the Axes object contains the limits for the left y-axis. However, if the right side is active, then the YLim property contains the limits for the right y-axis.

What I get from above description is that when you call `yyaxis`, another axes object is created an placed above the original one. But they are somehow internally coupled, so you can access their properties, including their separated lists of children, by activating them after calling `yyaxis` again.

Comment: Okay, but how does that help me change the order? I mean as long as their lists of children are seperated I cannot change the order, right? So I would have to change the order of the axis somehow instead ?

Comment: @Nils You can't! The right axis is always drown above the left axis. I also change order of plotting and it didn't work. All you can do is to alter axes themselves.

Comment: Hmm okay, so you are basically saying that it can not be done, correct?

Comment: @Nils To be more precise, all am I saying is that I failed to do that. The problem is, that these line objects do not belong to same parent. So changing their order is meaningless. What we can do here is to change order of their parents. But there are not two different axis objects!

Comment: Hmh okay, I understand.. Thanks for the help anyways.. I am surprised though that no one else seems to have stumbled upon this issue yet.